# Carbon-wrapped Aluminum seatpost?

Tags: touring, seatpost, carbon, aluminum

I have the seatpost shown in the pictures below. It came on a 2010 Specialized Tricross. It looks like Carbon fibre on the outside, but when you look at the open end of the tubing, it actually looks more like a thin layer of Carbon over a normal Aluminum tube.

[image: Outside of Seatpost]

[image: Inside of Seatpost]

I have two questions:

1. Am I correct that this tube is mostly aluminum with just a bit of carbon outside? If so, why would they even bother adding the Carbon? Just for show?
2. If it is mostly Aluminum, would it be acceptable for a long bike tour? From a durability perspective, that is. The reason I ask is I just got a new bike that came with a pretty basic metal tube with a hard to adjust seat clamp and less offset than this Carbon-wrapped one. I would prefer to use the Carbon seatpost from my Tricross since it has the offset I'm used to and a nicer seat clamp that's a bit easier to adjust fore/aft position and tilt separately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) It's for show, just like the carbon fiber insert on my Leatherman Skeletool CX. See this [question](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/6977/why-would-a-bike-feature-a-carbon-wrapped-aluminum-frame).

2) It's fine for touring provided its in good condition. However, you may still want to get a different seatpost depending on the adjustments available on this one.

Comment: It's hard to tell from the picture, but it looks like it may actually be a very thin inner layer of metal that used as a framework for the composite.  FSA makes carbon stems the same way.  The carbon is actually the majority structural component, the metal just provides a framework for a cheaper manufacturing process.  Looking at the line on that picture, the metal may make up less than a third of the width of the tube.  At that point the composite is hardly "for show".

Comment: It's an artifact of the angle of the picture.

Comment: Looks like it,  The spec sheet for that model / year lists it as "carbon wrapped".

Comment: Agreed. It's like the carbon fiber stickers that can be bought to adorn just about anything and make it look "custom" and/or "high tech": https://www.google.com/search?q=carbon+fiber+sticker&num=100&source=lnms&tbm=isch

Comment: Thanks for the feedback folks. I'll stick with this seatpost for my tour. I like the adjustments of the saddle mount on this one.

Comment: Though a full carbon post might be more comfortable through better flexibility.